# Example for setBackground() method

Tags: lightning-aura-components, actionfunction

I am trying to find an good example for setBackground() method on the action object, but came up with a code snippet that seems to be having lesser details.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_background_actions.htm

```
// set up the server-action action
var action = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
// optionally set actions params
//action.setParams({ firstName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });
// set as a background action
action.setBackground();
```

Question: How to get the return value from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value will be still returned via original method `setCallback`.

```
    // set up the server-action action
    const actionFunction = cmp.get("c.serverEcho");
    // optionally set actions params
    //action.setParams({ firstName : cmp.get("v.firstName") });
    // set as a background action

    // Here is the response
    actionFunction.setCallback(component,
        function (response) {
            const state = response.getState();
        })
    actionFunction.setBackground();
```

Nothing changes there.